# Some PC has error is Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 414 (Request-URI Too Long)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5.2, request-uri

In my team
some PC has this error
and some PC has not this error

- MVC version 5.2.2.0
- jQuery Validation Plugin 1.9.0

Error from Chrome

[image: Image show error]

I tried with IE and Firefox and error sill happen.

Please help me!
Thanks

Comment: Please never post error messages or code as a picture... it breaks the ability of this site to index for search.

Answer (score 0):

I tried setting below and it is worked!

[image]On top menu of Visual studio-> not checked into Enable Browser Link

Comment: Please never post error messages or code as a picture... it breaks the ability of this site to index for search.